# Summary with breakdown of dates by dayrange

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is raw table I have list of ids with dates and counts.  I need to pivot counts and break down date current date `getdate()` to date on the table broken out by 0-5 days , 10-15 ....

```
Type        Date         Volume
--------    -----        ------
primary     mar 10,2019     1
Sub         mar 8,2019      2
Pending     mar 13,2019     3
XX          mar 4,2019      5
```

What I want is, to show the result something like this:

```
TYPE     0-5 Days    5-10 Days    11-15 Days    16-20 Days    21-30 Days    Total
primary  1           4            1             6             1             13 
sub      3           5            5             7             0             20 
pending  1           1            1             1             1             5 
         5           10           7             14            2             38
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great that you've showed us what you're after, but you haven't asked us a question here; which is important so that we can help you. What is the problem you're having to achieve your goal? What have you tried so far and why isn't it working? Please do include your attempt(s) and explain what your question is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looking for a conditional sum of the volumes that compares the date with the current date. And with a rollup.

Then something like this :

```
SELECT Type,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[Date],GetDate()) BETWEEN 0  AND 5  THEN Volume ELSE 0 END) AS [0-5 Days],
 SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[Date],GetDate()) BETWEEN 6  AND 10 THEN Volume ELSE 0 END) AS [6-10 Days],
 SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[Date],GetDate()) BETWEEN 11 AND 15 THEN Volume ELSE 0 END) AS [11-15 Days],
 SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[Date],GetDate()) BETWEEN 16 AND 20 THEN Volume ELSE 0 END) AS [16-20 Days],
 SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[Date],GetDate()) BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN Volume ELSE 0 END) AS [21-30 Days],
 SUM(Volume) AS Total
FROM yourtable
WHERE [Date] >= CAST(GetDate()-30 AS DATE)
GROUP BY Type WITH ROLLUP
```